# Executing node.js script within casperjs or vice versa

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm working on an automation project using casperjs as the testing toolkit / framework. In one of my tests, the script is supposed to send automatic mails to specific prople in the organization.

The question is, is it possible to combine both node.js and casperjs/phantomjs scripts within one file? or is it possible to call for external scripts from casperjs?

Thanks ahead for any answer, 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Though both ways are possible I believe the simplest solution would be to launch mailer/script from CasperJS script.

CasperJS uses PhantomJS under the hood and the latter is able to exec/spawn child processes.

```
  var childProcess;
  try {
    childProcess = require("child_process");
  } catch (e) {
    this.log(e, "error");
  }
  if (childProcess) {
    childProcess.execFile("/bin/bash", ["mycommand.sh", args1, args2, args3], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      this.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout), 'debug');
      this.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr), 'debug');
    });
    this.log("Done", "debug");
  } else {
    this.log("Unable to require child process", "warning");
  }
```

From https://gist.github.com/clochix/6882184